# How to get a subset of a dataframe based on a list that corresponds to row indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
row|a|b|
0 |1|2
1 |2|0
2 |1|1
3 |3|2
4 |1|1
5 |1|0
```

I want to get the mean of each column but only for rows 1,3,4 and then compare with the mean for rows 0,2,5. The indices are stored in a numpy array `keep = np.array([1,3,4])` and `take = np.array([0,2,5])`. The ideal output would be an array or a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
keep |2|1
take |1|1
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

How about a concat:

```
pd.concat({'keep':df.iloc[keep].mean(), 
           'take':df.iloc[take].mean()}
         ).unstack()
```

Output:

```
        a    b
keep  2.0  1.0
take  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: that mostly worked! I ended up just saving them separately because the output shape was a little different from what I was looking for

Comment: So it's just the dictionary inside `pd.concat` then?

Comment: I just saw the revised answer and the unstack() worked great!!